# How can I make the angular interceptor work?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I made an interceptor to get a error when the bearer token expires, and a have two problems:

1 - The interceptor doesn't get the 401 error from the backend, instead the error.status has
the value 0

2 - When the interceptor receives the error, it logs out and removes the invalid token from the local storage but doesn't redirect to the login page

If anyone knows or has the same issues and can help, I appreciate it!

Code bellow:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{


    constructor(private tokenSerice: TokenService,
        private usuarioService: UsuarioService,
        private router: Router){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if(this.tokenSerice.hasToken()){
            const token = 'Bearer ' + this.tokenSerice.getToken();
            req = req.clone({
                    setHeaders:{
                        'Authorization': token,
                    },               
            })

        }
        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(error  => {
            error instanceof HttpResponse
            if(error.status === 401){
                this.usuarioService.logout();
                this.router.navigate(['']);
            }else{
                return throwError(error.message);
            }
        }))        
        
    }

}
```

I tried to add a pipe(like the example) but didn't work